# How to make python http requests with ntlm authentication using the user's session on linux

Tags: python, linux, authentication, ntlm

I have a python script that needs to make an http request (using the requests library) to an IIS server with ntlm authentication.

The script will run on a RedHat box, where the user's login credentials are authenticated with ActiveDirectory.

If you have a valid username/password for the AD domain, and therefore the web server, the use of requests-ntlm to authenticate to the server is obvious enough.

But what I'd like to do is to be able to authenticate to the web server using the user's session on the RedHat box, so the user doesn't have to type in their username & password again. Is this possible/how do you do this?